# selenium user profile in headless mode, chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, user-profile

**Situation**: i'm running chrome in headless mode (see arguments in section part of code), when i connect to page (let say i sign into the page before i run my app that's using selenium) i'm already login to page (because it's using existing profile and i login to page before i started my app) that's on first computer, correct PROFILE is used.

On second computer i'm running Chrome with same settings (same as on computer one) and when i go to the same page as on computer one i'm **NOT** login to the page (because the profile with existing session is not used)...

If i remove the --headless option everything works... **however i want to running it in HEADLESSS mode with current profile used by chrome.**

- **Driver**: Chrome driver version 101
- **Java version**: 15
- **Browser**: Google Chrome (version 101.0.4951.64)
- **Operating system**: both computers have Windows 10

**Part of code:**

```
                               String userP=getChromeUserProfilePath();
                                options.addArguments(String.format("--user-data-dir=%s",userP));
                          if(getChromeUserProfileName()!=null){
                                options.addArguments(String.format("--profile-directory=%s",getChromeUserProfileName()));
                            }
                               options.addArguments("--headless",
                                    "--disable-gpu",
                                    "--window-size=1920,1200",
                                    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                                    "--disable-extensions",
                                    "--no-sandbox",
                                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                 ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Questions:

**Where's the catch ? How do i make it work for second computer?**